# Java Characters Unicode/UTF-8 mismatch for non latin characters

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I am running into some issues with character encoding. I am passing in `太` into a Java method and its getting encoded/converted to `å¤ª`. This happens only locally and not on production, and only on non-latin characters.

I did some digging, and it turns out they are somehow related:

http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%C3%A5+%C2%A4+%C2%AA&mode=chars.

1. Is my setting/encoding on intellJ wrong?
2. Is there a way to convert `UTF-8 bytes as Latin-1 characters bytes` to `Character`

Comment: Where is this character coming from? Can you provide the method code?

Comment: MacOs and Linux uses UTF-8 as default encoding (for reading/writing/terminal), Windows not. So this seems you take implicitly UTF-8 on writing, without converting to locale charset. [but possibly setup your system to use UTF-8 console, so it has same behaviour as server

Comment: "*I am passing in `太` into a Java method and its getting encoded/converted to `å¤ª`*" - how are you passing it exactly? Is the caller also Java? Java strings are UTF-16 encoded, so `太` would be passed as `太` as expected. `å¤ª` is the UTF-8 encoded form of `太` misinterpreted as Latin-1. Java doesn't pass around strings as UTF-8, so does the method in question internally encode the input string to UTF-8 for some use (HDD storage, network transmission, etc)? Where exactly are you seeing the `å¤ª` appear?